# Tiered Sales Commission Stored Procedure using Lookup Table

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, lookup-tables

I want to calculate the commission for a salesperson based on variable scenarios:

the bid is above 82 cents and the term of the loans is 3 months and the dealer is an old dealer, then multiply the volume by different percentages based on the amount of the bid.

For example:

- Bid = 82 cents, old dealer, 3 month loan then volume * 3.00%
- Bid = 82 cents, new dealer, 3 month loan then volume * 3.25%
- Bid = 83 cents, old dealer, 3 month loan then volume * 2.75%.
- Bid = 83 cents, new dealer, 3 month loan then volume * 3.00%.

The percentage logic repeats for

- 6-month term( bids between 77 and 88)
- 9-month term( bids between 72 and 83)
- 12-month term( bids between 67 and 78)

I want the stored procedure to use a lookup table to drive the calculations:

Any ideas on how to go about this, or of good resources to design this table driven commission stored procedure?

Comment: create table CommissionLookUp
(
BaseBid float null,
NewDealer_OldDealer int null,
CommissionPercentage decimal(5,2) null,
Term_Months int null
) Here is my attempt at starting with a lookup table. I'm a novice.

Comment: I would suggest not using float for storing money values. It is an approximate datatype. You want an exact datatype like numeric for this. As for your actual question....huh??? Here is a good place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/